# sql Count Date and sum the amount

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasperserver

I would like to arrange the data into account statement format

Table A

```
Creditors name       Invoice No         Due date          Outstanding Amt
Company A            A001              1/8/2014            1500
Company B            A002              1/10/2014            300
Company B            A003              5/11/2014            900
Company B            A004              6/11/2014            50        
Company c            A005              31/12/2014           200
```

Statement Date: 31/12/14 (always change depend on current month), Expected output

```
Creditors name    0-30 Days    31-60 Days   61-90 Days   Over 90 Days   Amt Due        
Company A             0           0           0              1500         1500
Company B             0           950         0              300          1250
Company c            200          0           0               0           200
```

Please help & Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
select "Creditors name",
       SUM(case when "Due date" >= current_date - 30 then "Outstanding Amt" end) as "0-30 Days",
       SUM(case when "Due date" between current_date - 31 and current_date - 60 then "Outstanding Amt" end) as "31-60 Days",
       SUM(case when "Due date" between current_date - 61 and current_date - 90 then "Outstanding Amt" end) as "61-90 Days",
       SUM(case when "Due date" < current_date - 90 then "Outstanding Amt" end) as "Over 90 Days",
       SUM("Outstanding Amt") as "Amt Due"
from "Table A"
group by "Creditors name"
```

Date and intervals are always tricky to deal with since most dbms products behave differently, and I don't know how your dbms works. So you need to modify my code!

Comment: I try to use the query, but it shows error message com.jaspersoft.commons.semantic.metaapi.MetaDataException: Cannot execute JDBC Query.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-182, SQLSTATE=42816, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.64.114

Answer (score 0):

Something like below may work

```
Select 
creditor_name,
sum(case when datediff(day,due_date,getdate()) between 0 and 30 then [Outstanding Amt] else 0 end) as [0-30 days],
sum(case when datediff(day,due_date,getdate()) between 31 and 60 then [Outstanding Amt] else 0 end) as [0-30 days],
.
.
.
from table
group by creditor_name,
```